# SOLR HTTP 500 Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml'

Tags: solr, lucene, coldfusion-9

I have Apache SOLR working with ColdFusion on my local machine, however, when I tried to make the move to production (environments are different), I keep getting the HTTP 500 message below. Production environment is using Ubuntu Lucid, Apache, ColdFusion 9.0.1. Using the version of SOLR installed with ColdFusion.

The path for solrconfig.xml in the error message, "/opt/jrun4/servers/prod-autofeed1/cfusion.ear/cfusion.war/WEB-INF/cfusion/collections/autofeed/conf/" is correct.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

**HTTP ERROR: 500**

Severe errors in solr configuration.

Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.

If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change:

```
 <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError>

in solr.xml

-------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/opt/jrun4/servers/prod-autofeed1/cfusion.ear/cfusion.war/WEB-INF/cfusion/collections/autofeed/conf/', cwd=/opt/jrun4/servers/cfusion/cfusion-ear/cfusion-war/WEB-INF/cfusion/solr
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:260)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:228)
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:101)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:130)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:405)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:278)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:117)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:83)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:99)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:594)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:139)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:500)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:161)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:210)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:929)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:183)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115)
RequestURI=/solr/

Powered by Jetty://
```

Comment: @Frank, that was the issue! I had copied over my schema.xml and solrconfig.xml files to production and completely forgot about permissions. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Frank, I cannot seem to give you credit for the answer?

Comment: Reposted as an answer (which maybe I should have done in the first place) if you want to accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check permissions on the directory `/opt/jrun4/servers/prod-autofeed1/cfusion.ear/cfusion.war/WEB-INF/cfusion/collections/autofeed/conf` and the file `/opt/jrun4/servers/prod-autofeed1/cfusion.ear/cfusion.war/WEB-INF/cfusion/collections/autofeed/conf/solrconfig.xml`. If the user solr is run under can't read the dir/file, that'd do it. To test, you might even `su` to the user in question and simply try to `cat` the config file.